# sql SYNTAX ERROR IN CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following format.

```
EMP NUMBER, ATT DATE,   ATT TIME
00001   01-03-2018  08:45
00001   01-03-2018  20:50
00001   02-03-2018  08:00
00001   02-03-2018  18:50
```

I was asked to get the following results:

```
EMP NUMBER,  ATT DATE,    IN TIME,   OUT TIME
00001      01-03-2018   08:45     20:50
00001      02-03-2018   08:00     18:50
```

Which I managed to get using the following query:

```
SELECT EMP_NUMBER, ATT_DATE,MIN(ATT_TIME) AS IN_TIME,MAX(ATT_TIME) AS OUT_TIME 
        INTO TABLE1
FROM FJ 
GROUP BY EMP_NUMBER,ATT_DATE
```

Even though I get the answers I wanted but I am worried about the condition when an Employee Login at night by 10pm and leaves by the following morning 5pm, hence I tried the following:

```
SELECT EMP_NUMBER, ATT_DATE,
        CASE
            WHEN ATT_TIME >= 12
            THEN MIN(ATT_TIME)
            ELSE MAX(ATT_TIME)
            AS IN_TIME,
        CASE
            WHEN ATT_TIME < 12
                THEN MIN(ATT_TIME)
                ELSE MAX(ATT_TIME)
         AS OUT_TIME,
         INTO TABLE1
    FROM FJ 
    GROUP BY EMP_NUMBER,ATT_DATE
```

Which throws a syntax error near "AS", could you please help me to figure out where I am going wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me you should find a different keyboard. The one you're using now seems to have a stuck CAPS LOCK key. You should replace it, because you don't want people here (or anywhere else on the internet) to think you're SHOUTING at them.

Comment: Please, stop SHOUTING! And the syntax for case is `CASE ... END`. You forgot the `END`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the query logic but you are missing "END" clause for your both CASE statements.

```
SELECT EMP_NUMBER, ATT_DATE,
        CASE
            WHEN ATT_TIME >= 12
            THEN MIN(ATT_TIME)
            ELSE MAX(ATT_TIME)
         END               --<-- You are missing "END" here 
            AS IN_TIME,
        CASE
            WHEN ATT_TIME < 12
                THEN MIN(ATT_TIME)
                ELSE MAX(ATT_TIME)
         END                    --<-- and here 
         AS OUT_TIME  --<-- also you had an extra comma here
         INTO TABLE1
    FROM FJ 
    GROUP BY EMP_NUMBER,ATT_DATE
```

Comment: well yes it does solve the error, ended up with a new one Msg 156, 
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'".

Comment: @balasubramanie yes you also had an extra comma there see my answer carefully

Comment: sorry my mistake